# Is default pwm frequency 19.2Mhz in raspberry 3+?

Tags: gpio, c

But when i set clock to 1920 and range 200, I got the frequency 5KHz rather than 50HZ from oscilloscope, does anyone explain that, what's the problem. Thanks

my code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<wiringPi.h>

#define port 23
#define mode PWM_MODE_BAL

int main(int arglen, char *argv[])
{
      int index = 0;
      if ( arglen < 2)
      {
              printf("input port number \n");
              exit(1);
      }
      if(-1==wiringPiSetup())
      {
             printf("setup error\n");
             exit(-1);
      }

    int divisor = 1920;
    int range = 200;
    int dutycycle = 512;
    wiringPiSetup();
    pwmSetRange(range);
    pinMode(port,PWM_OUTPUT);

    pwmSetMode(mode);
    pwmSetClock(divisor);
    for (index= 0;index<10000;index++)
    {
        pwmWrite(port,dutycycle);
        delay(340);
        pwmWrite(port,0);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The crystal oscillator is 19.2 MHz on all Pi models earlier than the Pi4B.  The Pi4B is based on the new BCM2711 which has a 54 MHz oscillator.  It is likely that all future BCM2711 based Pis will also be 54 MHz.

Don't use balanced PWM if you want a particular frequency, use mark space.

Balanced will try to achieve the desired duty cycle as "smoothly" as possible.  For instance if you ask for a dutycycle of 50% that can be achieved at any frequency, but it will appear "smoother" at 100 kHz then it would at 1 Hz.

See page 139 of [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @joan. If I want to output a PWM with 4.4M ,when I set range to 255, according the the formula:pwmFrequency in Hz = 19.2e6 Hz / pwmClock / pwmRange, 
19200000/4400000/255, I got 1. It seams wrong.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the wiringPi internals.  pigpio will give a figure of 4385965 if you select 4.4M as a frequency (sudo pigpiod; pigs hp 12 4400000 500000).

Comment: would u pls give more details. I want to output PWM with frequency 4.4M, but when I used the PWM_MODE_BAL mode, I can not get the correct frequency.

Comment: As I said I am not that familiar with wiringPi.